# How to convert a dec to a 32bit int in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript how would i convert a integer into a fixed 32bit integer. And then how could i append this to the start of a string, but still as a 32bit int?

Thankyou !

### Answer

Turns out it cant be done.....

Comment: Javascript doesnt know decimal int's, nor 32 bit ints. Only numbers [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make much sense. What is "a dec"? How would a 32bit int prepended to a string look? Can you give examples of the input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickly , you could use the  [Math object in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp)

Javascript does not know if it is an INT. It only knows numbers.

Then to append a string to a number just do something like :

```
var my_int = 45.25;
var my_str = 'Hello Wolrd';
document.write(my_int+my_str); // echo 45.25Hello World
```

Comment: So javascript has no override functions so it can understand binary based actions ? Thankyou javascript -.-"

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you're asking here.  Javascript has numbers and strings.  A number can either have a decimal component or not.  They don't have a separate type that is integers.  You can convert a number that has a decimal component to one that does not using the Math library (or several other ways too) if you want.  You can put a number into a string by just adding it on.  Here's an example:

```
var decimal = Math.PI;   // start out with a decimal number
var rounded = Math.round(decimal);
var str = "'" + rounded + " is the final result'";
alert(" " + decimal + ", " + rounded + ", " + str);
// alerts 3.141592653589793, 3, '3 is the final result'
```

You can see this code actually run here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZkMvw/